# Salesforce Action buttons in enhancedlist

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

Is there a way to add a custom button to the action section of the apex:enhancedlist?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 1):

Frank,

To my knowledge you cannot create an <apex:commandbutton> from which you can invoke controller actions, however you can create a 'Custom Buttons and Links' style button from the setup menu. If you go to the Custom Buttons and Links section for the sObject that you are feeding to the type attribute of your enchanced list, you can create a button whose display type is 'List Button'. Then it will show up on any enhanced list component of that sObject type. As I mentioned, you can't invoke a controller action, but you can navigate to an arbitrary URL, display a Visualforce page, or run arbitrary javascript that way. Hope that help you.